# OrderByDescending not working properly in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Linq and have the following code in C#:

```
leaves = GetAnnualLeaves();
otherleaves = GetOtherLeaves();
leaves.AddRange(otherleaves);
leaves.OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate);
```

Basically I am trying to display list of annual and other leaves and I want to display them in DESCENDING order. Problem is it always shows "Other Leaves" at the end of "Annual Leaves" no matter what. So basically it displays like this:

```
2013-06-29 Annual
2012-01-01 Annual
2011-05-02 Annual
2013-05-01 Other
```

When in fact it should display like this:

```
2013-06-29 Annual
2013-05-01 Other
2012-01-01 Annual
2011-05-02 Annual
```

Any idea why order by descending is not working?

**EDIT**

I am getting casting error when I use CONCAT.

Both "Annual" and "Other" leaves are of same type but when I do

```
leaves = leaves.Concat(otherleaves)
```

then the project doesn't compile and gives error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyEntity> to System.Collections.Generic.List<MyEntity>
```

And if I do type cast:

```
leaves = (List<MyEntity>)leaves.Concat(otherleaves)
```

then I get runtime error.

Comment: `leaves = leaves.OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate);`? Or change the variable, if the types don't match.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't assign result of `OrderByDescending`

```
leaves = leaves.OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate).ToList();
```

or do

```
leaves = leaves.Concat(otherleaves).OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate).ToList();
```

Comment: I did the first code but still same issue. Now within Annual Leaves items are sorted but Other Leaves are still at the end.

Comment: And `leaves.AddRange(otherleaves);` is called before that? did you try second example?

Comment: Yes this is before the Order by code. Let me try second example.

Comment: I used second code and now Other Leaves are not even displaying :)

Comment: There is a typo. Should be `Concat` instead of `Concate` but other then that it works here.

Comment: Yes I have used Concat but it turns our it is not concatinating Other Leaves. So before concatination there are 50 records in "leaves" and after this code there are still 50 records in "leaves" when it should have been 52 as 2 "other leaves" record are concatinated.

Comment: So `leaves` is `List<SomeClass>` and has 50 items, `otherLeaves` has 2 and after you call `ToList()` and overwrite `leaves` with new list it still has 50 items?

Comment: Oh I see there is an exception coming which I didn't notice. Let me see how to fix that exception.

Comment: I am getting casting error when I use CONCAT. Both "Annual" and "Other" leaves are of same type but when I do "leaves = leaves.Concat(otherleaves)" then it gives error "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyEntity> to System.Collections.Generic.List<MyEntity>".     And if I do type cast "leaves = (List<MyEntity>)leaves.Concat(otherleaves)" then I get runtime error.

Comment: you need to call `ToList()` before you assign it `leaves.Concat(otherleaves).ToList()` or do `leaves.Concat(otherleaves).OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate).ToList()` but you need to call `ToList()` before you assign it back. Casting will cause error

Comment: @FrankMartin, LINQ has deferred execution which means when you do `Concat(otherleaves)` it won't concat immediately so you can keep adding other things like `Select`, `Where` or `OrderByDescending` and it won't be called immediately until you call method like `ToList()` or start iterating through items which will execute all operations in most optimal way giving you one result list. That's why you need to call `ToList()` to assign it back

Answer (score 2):

`OrderByDescending` does not "sort in place". It rather returns an `IOrderedEnumerable` that you must assign to a variable.

```
var orderedLeaves = leaves.OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate);
```

Comment: Now within Annual Leaves items are sorted but Other Leaves are still at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> OrderByDescending

doesn't order a list, it returns a new ordered `IEnumerable`. So use **the result** of `OrderByDescending` to display your items.