# How to Order By or Sort an integer List and select the Nth element

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I have a list, and I want to select the fifth highest element from it:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

list.Add(2);
list.Add(18);
list.Add(21);
list.Add(10);
list.Add(20);
list.Add(80);
list.Add(23);
list.Add(81);
list.Add(27);
list.Add(85);
```

But `OrderbyDescending` is not working for this `int` list...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21726334/613130 for an explanation about what is happening.

Comment: Note that by using a `OrderBy` you are transforming what should be a O(N) operation in a O(NlogN) operation.

Comment: @Fabjan `OrderBy` doesn't "order" the `list`. It returns a ordered `IEnumerable<>`. He is probably doing `list.OrderByDescending(x => x);`, no assignment.

Comment: @xanatos It would be nice if OP has added an [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where he shows what he *tried* to do and what exactly is not working

Comment: @Fabjan I always thought that a minimum level of long-distance mind-reading was necessary on SO :-) But you are right.

Comment: Some interesting theoretical knowledge about picking the nth highest/lowest element in an unsorted collection: https://stackoverflow.com/q/251781/613130

Comment: You should specify what to do when there are 4 or less elements, when that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
int fifth = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).Skip(4).First();
```

Comment: This approach throws an exception when the list is too small, which can lead to performance issues. @bommelding: you need to add an `if(list.Count >= 5)` guard wrapping this code to mitigate the issue.

Comment: Agreed, but I will leave it as-is, unless the OP specifies it better. A Count could cost, and what to return for fewer items?   The contract could guarantee there always is a fifth.

Comment: The cost of the `if` guard is NONE compared with the cost of creating the enumerable AND sorting everything with `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: I said _could_ , like when the source is not an in-memory List but a Queryable.

Answer (score 1):

Without **LINQ** expressions:

```
int result;
if(list != null && list.Count >= 5)
{
    list.Sort();
    result = list[list.Count - 5];
}
else // define behavior when list is null OR has less than 5 elements
```

This has a better performance compared to LINQ expressions, although the [LINQ solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50715504/823321) presented in my second answer are comfortable and reliable.

In case you need extreme performance for a huge List of integers, I'd recommend a more specialized algorithm, like in [Matthew Watson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50716451/823321).

**Attention**: The List gets modified when the `Sort()` method is called. If you don't want that, you must work with a copy of your list, like this:

```
List<int> copy = new List<int>(original);

List<int> copy = original.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the severity of the list not having more than 5 elements you have 2 options.

If the list never should be over 5 i would catch it as an exception:

```
int fifth;
try
{
    fifth = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).ElementAt(4);
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
    //Handle the exception
}
```

If you expect that it will be less than 5 elements then you could leave it as default and check it for that.

```
int fifth = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).ElementAtOrDefault(4);

if (fifth == 0)
{
    //handle default
}
```

This is still some what flawed because you could end up having the fifth element being 0. This can be solved by typecasting the list into a list of nullable ints at before the linq:

```
var newList = list.Select(i => (int?)i).ToList();
int? fifth = newList.OrderByDescending(x => x).ElementAtOrDefault(4);

if (fifth == null)
{
    //handle default
}
```

Comment: I didn't see the nullable int trick in the third block. Although now this does not seem to be a high performance solution, since it first creates a copy of the list, and then generates an enumerable during the LINQ expression

Comment: Well you could ram it together in one line. However the conversion would be more subtle then. Tuning on performance is not included in this answer, since it isn't part of the question.

Comment: See both answers I've posted, which cover the case when the list itself is `null` OR it has less than 5 elements on it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to just sort the data and take N items from the front. This is the recommended way for small data sets - anything more complicated is just not worth it otherwise.

However, for large data sets it can be a lot quicker to do what's known as a [`Partial Sort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting).

There are two main ways to do this: Use a heap, or use a specialised quicksort.

The article I linked describes how to use a heap. I shall present a partial sort below:

```
public static IList<T> PartialSort<T>(IList<T> data, int k) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = data.Count - 1;

    while (end > start)
    {
        var index = partition(data, start, end);
        var rank = index + 1;

        if (rank >= k)
        {
            end = index - 1;
        }
        else if ((index - start) > (end - index))
        {
            quickSort(data, index + 1, end);
            end = index - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            quickSort(data, start, index - 1);
            start = index + 1;
        }
    }

    return data;
}

static int partition<T>(IList<T> lst, int start, int end) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T x = lst[start];
    int i = start;

    for (int j = start + 1; j <= end; j++)
    {
        if (lst[j].CompareTo(x) < 0) // Or "> 0" to reverse sort order.
        {
            i = i + 1;
            swap(lst, i, j);
        }
    }

    swap(lst, start, i);
    return i;
}

static void swap<T>(IList<T> lst, int p, int q)
{
    T temp = lst[p];
    lst[p] = lst[q];
    lst[q] = temp;
}

static void quickSort<T>(IList<T> lst, int start, int end) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (start >= end)
        return;

    int index = partition(lst, start, end);
    quickSort(lst, start, index - 1);
    quickSort(lst, index + 1, end);
}
```

Then to access the 5th largest element in a list you could do this:

```
PartialSort(list, 5);
Console.WriteLine(list[4]);
```

For large data sets, a partial sort can be significantly faster than a full sort.

---

**Addendum**

See [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quickselect_algorithm#C.23) for another (probably better) solution that uses a [QuickSelect algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

Comment: This is a very nice solution for large datasets, thank you a lot this contribution +1. Just a question for clarifying: Does this algorithm sort the list until the Kth sorted element is found, and then it exits?

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp Yes, effectively it does (so it *usually* reduces the amount of work significantly). The expected complexity is `O(n + k log k)` - however, be aware that the worst-case time can be quite bad (this is noted in the Wikipedia article that I linked).

Answer (score 0):

This **LINQ** approach retrieves the 5th biggest element **OR** throws an exception **WHEN** the list is null or contains less than 5 elements:

```
int fifth = list?.Count >= 5 ?
    list.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(5).Last() :
    throw new Exception("list is null OR has not enough elements");
```

This one retrieves the 5th biggest element **OR** `null` **WHEN** the list is `null` or contains less than 5 elements:

```
int? fifth = list?.Count >= 5 ?
    list.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(5).Last() :
    default(int?);

if(fifth == null) // define behavior
```

This one retrieves the 5th biggest element **OR** the smallest element **WHEN** the list contains less than 5 elements:

```
if(list == null || list.Count <= 0)
    throw new Exception("Unable to retrieve Nth biggest element");

int fifth = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(5).Last();
```

All these solutions are reliable, they should **NEVER** throw "unexpected" exceptions.

**PS**: I'm using **.NET 4.7** in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/03/more-ilist-extension-methods.html) there is a C# implementation of the [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm to select the nth element in an unordered `IList<>`.

You have to put all the code contained in that page in a `static class`, like:

```
public static class QuickHelpers
{
    // Put the code here
}
```

Given that "library" (in truth a big fat block of code), then you can:

```
int resA = list.QuickSelect(2, (x, y) => Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(y, x));
int resB = list.QuickSelect(list.Count - 1 - 2);
```

Now... Normally the `QuickSelect` would select the nth lowest element. We reverse it in two ways:

- For `resA` we create a reverse comparer based on the default `int` comparer. We do this by reversing the parameters of the `Compare` method. Note that the index is 0 based. So there is a 0th, 1th, 2th and so on.
- For `resB` we use the fact that the 0th element is the *list-1* th element in the reverse order. So we count from the back. The highest element would be the `list.Count - 1` in an ordered list, the next one `list.Count - 1 - 1`, then `list.Count - 1 - 2` and so on

Theorically using Quicksort should be better than ordering the list and then picking the nth element, because ordering a list is on average a O(NlogN) operation and picking the nth element is then a O(1) operation, so the composite is O(NlogN) operation, while QuickSelect is on average a O(N) operation. Clearly there is a but. The O notation doesn't show the `k` factor... So a O(k1 * NlogN) with a small k1 could be better than a O(k2 * N) with a big k2. Only multiple real life benchmarks can tell us (you) what is better, and it depends on the size of the collection.

A small note about the algorithm:

> As with quicksort, quickselect is generally implemented as an in-place algorithm, and beyond selecting the k'th element, it also partially sorts the data. See selection algorithm for further discussion of the connection with sorting.

So it modifies the ordering of the original `list`.